# Latest event - rewards?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Today a new decorator droid event started. Is it worth to spend bux on calling droids? 
What are the rewards for this event, meaning how many floors do you have to decorate in order to receive which rewards?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the limited edition rewards for this event would be a character, and then a level, similar to the previous two events which had the same reward structure. First reward would be a costume, awarded when you complete decorating **10** floors. And the next reward comes when you finish decorating **30** floors. The Overbridge level is awarded when you decorate **60** floors.

To answer your other questions: Unlike the past 2 events where I didn't have to spend a single bux (provided you play quite regularly), I have had to spend bux to get ALL but 3-4 of my Decorator Droids (I'm currently up to 33/60 decorations). Decorator Droids seem much much harder to come by for this event.

The character reward should be Grand Moff Tarkin - awarded for decorating 30 floors.
[image: Limited Edition Char]

[image: Grand Moff Tarkin]

And the level reward should be the Overbridge - awarded for decorating 60 floors.
[image: Overbridge]

Answer (score 0):

Grand midfield Tarkin is at 30